# Como gerenciar o estado de uma variável sem chamadas a API

Tags: react, redux

Com o `reducer`:

```
import {
    HIDE_MENU,
    ESTADO_MENU
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    open: true
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case HIDE_MENU:
            return {
                ...state,
                open: false
            }
        case ESTADO_MENU:
            return {
                ...state
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

e a `action`:

```
import {
    HIDE_MENU,
    ESTADO_MENU
} from './types';

export const hideMenu = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: HIDE_MENU,
        data: false
    })
}

export const estadoDoMenu = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: ESTADO_MENU
    })
}
```

Quando eu chamo no componente:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTotalUsuariosBloqueados();
    this.props.fetchTotalSolicitacao();

    console.log("Estado do Menu: " + this.props.estadoDoMenu());
    if (this.props.estadoDoMenu() == true) this.setState({ open: false });
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchTotalUsuariosBloqueados,
  fetchTotalSolicitacao,
  estadoDoMenu,
  hideMenu
})(onClickOutside(Menu));
```

Ele da como `undefined`, o que que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Matheus, seria bom você colocar o trecho do componente onde você chama essa função. Vc passou ela pelo mapDispatchToProps? Outro detalhe é que sua função não tem retorno, então o retorno é undefined (void) mesmo.

Comment: botei, o que faço dai?

Comment: Você conectou o redux ao componente?

Comment: seria isso ai que ta no final? botei na pergunta